# where can i find wso2 jars to import into my program

Tags: jar, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have been trying to follow the example at http://xacmlinfo.com/2011/12/18/writing-jdbc-pip-module/ in order to create a pip for the wso2 identity server and I cannot get it to work because I cannot import wso2 jars.  I have tried using maven to build the projects thinking that maven would automatically download the necessary dependencies but it does not. could anyone please tell me were I could get the wso2 jars or point me in the right direction in order to be able to compile wso2 java programs.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey guys I figured it out, the packages for wso2 identity server programming are shipped with identity server.  they are located in IS_HOME\repository\components\plugins.  thanks guys for your help

Answer (score 0):

All the released wso2 jars are hosted in wso2-nexus repository. You can simply add wso2-nexus under repositories for your app to download the wso2 released jars.
Following would help

```
<repository>
    <id>wso2-nexus</id>
    <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
    <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
    </releases>
</repository>
```